# HTML automatically sets the size of iframe to the size of the div / window

Tags: html, css, iframe, resize

I want to automatically set the size of my iframe to the maximum still possible size without overlapping any other stuff.

Currently my site looks like this:

[image: my site)]

but the iframe with "Second Test-Page" should cover up everything below the navbar.

My index.html looks like this:

```css
div#content {
    background-color:transparent;
}

.content > div {
    display: none;
}

.content > div:target {
    display: table-row;
}

iframe {
    display: block;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">Test-Site</div>

    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#test">Sub-Page1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#test1">Sub-Page2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub-Page3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
        <div id="test">
            <iframe src="test.html"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="test1">
            <iframe src="test1.html"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

You give below CSS to the `iframe` so It is take remaining full height in window

```
iframe{
 min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
 width:100%;
}
```

so need to Subtract whatever want extra height.

It is taking full height of window as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?  If this is what you wanted, then what I did was remove the display none as it did not allow the i-frame to take up max space

```css
div#content {
    background-color:transparent;
}

.content > div {
    
}

.content > div:target {
    display: table-row;
}

iframe {
    display: block;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">Test-Site</div>

    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#test">Sub-Page1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#test1">Sub-Page2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub-Page3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
        <div id="test">
            <iframe src="test.html"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="test1">
            <iframe src="test1.html"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```